# Github - Creating a fork and later merging upstream changes without sending my changes back

Tags: git, github, github-for-windows

We are having rapid continuous development on a project so the developers repository changes every few days.

I'm unfamiliar with Git and Github

I was originally downloading the repository as a zip and then making some changes locally specific to our needs. Doing a windiff each time to confirm changed files and manually resolving any conflicts with the files that I had changed locally and any new updates from the developer's repository.

As this was cumbersome I then created a clone of the remote repository locally and if there was a conflict with the files that I changed locally when I did a fetch, I would stash my local files and then manually add my changed lines back in after fetching the remote branch.

I then thought it may be easier to fork the repository make changes to my fork and then merge any changes from the developer automatically by fetching the latest commits form them. I've been using a combination of github.com and github desktop for Windows.

However now there is a conflict - I presume with changes I have made to the same file(s) the developers have now changed.

> This branch is 6 commits behind the upstream and has conflicts that must be resolved.
> Open a pull request to fetch upstream and review changes or resolve conflicts.

However from what I have read this will send my changes back upstream to the developer for them to accept into their repository?

I want to create changes locally and not return them upstream and just merge changes from upstream into my fork and manually deal with conflicts line by line in the file. Currently, and probably incorrectly, I have forked and have made local changes in the Master Branch.

What is the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You should probably do all your custom work in a separate branch. Initial setup would look something like this:

- `git clone` the remote repository
- `git checkout -b updates` to create and move to a new branch
- Make your changes on the `updates` branch

After the initial setup, you could do the following whenever the remote repo was updated:

- `git checkout master` to switch to the "clean" version of the repo
- `git fetch` to pull down remote changes
- `git checkout updates` to switch back to the branch with your local modifications
- `git merge master` to initiate a merge of the updated code and manually deal with any conflicts

See https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge for more information on the merge command.

Answer (score 0):

OK I am not clear why you are doing this - it you give the usecase you may get a better suggestion. E.g. if it is for a build system then possibly the extras could be injected some other way, such as making the developers' version configurable or secrets (say) added outside git; and if for deployment then the developers' version ought not to differ that much from the deployment. There are often other ways to do things that can be simpler - e.g. using traditional patches.

Having said that, for this approach I would look to rebase your mods to the latest version of main/master from time to time and handle any conflicts at that point. Using rebase rather than merge in this case will give you a cleaner history (you just see your own few additions to the main branch all the time) and make it simpler to focus on what to do should the developer version start to radically change.

Comment: A few reasons - some is temporary fixes for using it on a different platform, some are quicks hacks, extra debug code, changing some fixed defaults etc As it is only in test and rapid development it doesn't need permanent changes at this point and very little of my mangled code would be for production/final release.

Comment: I will basically stick with my rebase argument, although if what you are doing changes based on upstream you could consider leaving the original in place and using cherry-pick instead - rebase is after all essentially cherry-pick plus deleting the old commits. You would need of course to use a new branch name each time. May or may not be useful....